# How can we use "do"

Tags: meaning

If I have to write the same name many times like

> Ramesh Mishra
>   Ramesh Mishra

I can write it as

> Ramesh Mishra
>   ----do-------

Here, what is the meaning of *do*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What is the context— where why would you be writing the same name many times? Who says that *do* represents a repetition, or where have you seen it used? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to write questions that are answerable at this site.

Answer (score 2):

it is short for 'ditto' which is the Latin/Italian for 'as before'